# Migrate from TFVC to git, new git directory structure and maintain TFVC changeset history

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc

I'm attempting to migrate multiple projects within a single TFVC repository to a new git repository.  I want to retain the file/directory changeset history - I don't care about project work items, etc.

I've found multiple examples for migrating from TFVC to git, however, I want to re-org the directory structure of the new git repository, so my goal is to move a single TFVC project at a time.  Is there a way to do this and retain the file changeset history?

The examples I have found show to clone the original repository, cleanup the files from TFVC for git, then push the entire repository to git or push single projects which retain the original directory structure - which is not what I want.

Comment: Detailed steps of Migrating a TFVC team project to a Git team project along with changeset history in TFS, you can refer to blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/05/19/migrating-a-tfvc-team-project-to-a-git-team-project-along-with-changeset-history-in-tfs/

Answer (score 2):

Migrate your repository normally, then reorganize it. Or reorganize it, then convert it to a Git repository.

There are no tools that are going to propagate your reorganized folder structure backwards through the commit history.

Comment: That's what I was seeing from my research.  Thanks for your confirmation!

Answer (score -1):

You can download and use Git-TFS to clone ant folder or bran h structure in TFVC and output a Git repo with the full history.

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

This is normally a bad idea as most folks using a server based source control system (like TFVC or Subversion) end up with significant baggage that they don't want in Git. Much of this baggage are binaries...